# ASP.NET intermittent DB2 connection problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, db2, windows-server-2008-r2

We have an ASP.NET MVC application using DB2 connections to an iSeries to acquire user settings. We host the site on a web farm of 4 Windows 2008 R2 SP1 servers.

Occasionally, any queries to DB2 coming from one of the servers will fail with the message "A communication error occurred". Additionally, that server is sometimes unable to acquire user session from our session state server when this communication error occurs with the error "Unable to make the session state request to the session state server...". It does regularly communicate with a different server for SQL Server queries during this event though. The other 3 servers in the farm are fine and if we reboot the problem server, it returns to normal.

Looking at Event Viewer shows no clues as to why the server suddenly has communication issues. Server metrics look normal as well. The issue happens intermittently on any of the 4 servers. This started happening a few months ago and has been happening more frequently the last few weeks. Prior, we were running for years with our current setup and are confident no changes in the code would be affecting this. Any help on what the issue could be or how to troubleshoot would be greatly appreciated. Here is our code snippet if that is any help

```
using (var cn = new iDB2Connection("ConnectionTimeout=45;Pooling=true;MinimumPoolSize=1;MaximumPoolSize=-1;MaximumUseCount=100;CheckConnectionOnOpen=true;DataSource=XXX;Naming=SQL;DataCompression=True;UserID=XXX;password=XXX;"))
        {
            try
            {
                cn.Open();

                using (var cmd = new iDB2Command(query, cn))
                {
                    //execute reader
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //generate error email
            }
            finally
            {
                if (cn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    cn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you have a `using` statement, there's no need for your `finally` block.

Comment: I'd say it's a network problem, since the DB2 connectivity error coincides with the "session state server" connectivity error.

Comment: One iseries troubleshooting technique:  dspobjd *all on the iseris to an *outfile.  Then query the outfile for objects that were changed 4 months ago.  or check the qzdasoinit jobs on the iseries